# How to add element to various container depending of type using template

Tags: c++, templates

I've got rather silly question but I hope that you can help me with that.

I've got class with multiple vectors, and this vectors have different storage types.

```
class BaseClass{
  std::string Name;
}

class B : public BaseClass{

}
class C : public BaseClass{

}

class A{
  vector<std::pair<std::string, B>> V1;
  vector<std::pair<std::string, C>> V2;
}
```

inside my class A there is a template function to add elements to this vectors:

```
template <class T>  void addElement(T Obj);
```

I want this situation to happen:

```
A a;
B b;
C c;


a.addElement<B>(b) -> then element b is added to vector V1
a.addElement<C>(c) -> then element c is added to vector V2
```

I came up with something like this:

```
template <class T>  void addElement(T Obj){
  std::pair<std::string, T> AddedPair(Obj.Name, Obj);

   if (typeid(T) == typeid(B)) 
    V1.push_back(AddedPair);

   if (typeid(T) == typeid(C)) 
    V2.push_back(AddedPair);

}
```

But unfortunetly this code won't compile because somehow template is compiled as a whole and if I use B as a template argument then compiler cannot convert B to C despite that program will never reach a point where this convertions can happened :(

Do you have any suggestions how can I solve this problem? I would be very greatful.

Comment: Look up template specialization and SFINAE.

Comment: Just create overloads of the function that take different types. This is not really a generic. What happens if I pass type D to it

Comment: But there will be 15 - 20 different types of this vectors not only B,C so I don;t want to create 15 - 20 overloaded functions :/

Comment: just as much code gets typed, in fact maybe less -

Comment: I simplyfied this template function, at the beginning it is checking if the type is compatible

Comment: if you have 20 `vector<std::pair<std::string, T>>` why another 20 `void addElement(T Obj)` is problem? If those `vector`s are template generated, then generate the corresponded `addElement` at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having

```
template <class T>  void addElement(T Obj);
```

Just overload the function instead.  That would give you

```
void addElement(const B& Obj)
{
    V1.push_back({Obj.Name, Obj});
}

void addElement(const C& Obj)
{
    V2.push_back({Obj.Name, Obj});
}
```

This saves you all the syntax of specializing the template or needing C++17 and [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) to make the decision at compile time.

---

The reason

```
template <class T>  void addElement(T Obj){
std::pair<std::string, T> AddedPair(Obj.Name, Obj);

    if (typeid(T) == typeid(B)) 
        V1.push_back(AddedPair);

    if (typeid(T) == typeid(C)) 
        V2.push_back(AddedPair);

}
```

Doesn't work is the code in each if block needs to be valid (even if it could never be reached), but it can't be because you would be adding a different type into the vectors.  `if constexpr` helps but I find overloading is just as much typing and makes the code non-backwards compatible.

That means you would either have to specialize the template like

```
template <class T>  void addElement(T Obj);

template <>  void addElement(B Obj)
{
    V1.push_back({Obj.Name, Obj});
}   
template <>  void addElement(C Obj)
{
    V1.push_back({Obj.Name, Obj});
}
```

or using `if constexpr`:

```
template <class T>  void addElement(T Obj){
std::pair<std::string, T> AddedPair(Obj.Name, Obj);

    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, B>) 
        V1.push_back(AddedPair);

    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, C>) 
        V2.push_back(AddedPair);

}
```

Comment: yup, generics gets waaay too overused (same in c# land)

Comment: But I just said this will be 15 - 20 diferent types, so 15 - 20 functions. I will probably use overload but hipotetical is there a way to use template - right now I'm just curious

Comment: @Sawyer I've updated the answer to show all of your options.

Comment: Thank you. And I will use your advice regarding overloading ;)

Answer (score 1):

This may be a use case for a [Tagged Tuple library](https://github.com/guaranteed-to-be-unique/Tagged-Tuple). It makes it possible to index containers by associated type. So code dealing with dozens of similar `vector<std::pair<std::string, B>> V1;` fields becomes generic:

```
#include <vtt/container/Tagged Tuple.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

class BaseClass{::std::string Name;};
class B : public BaseClass{};
class C : public BaseClass{};

class A
{
    public: template<typename x_Item> using
    t_Vector = ::std::vector<::std::pair<::std::string, x_Item>>;

    public: using
    t_Vectors = ::n_vtt::n_container::t_TaggedTuple
    <// index type -> value type mapping
        B, t_Vector<B>
    ,   C, t_Vector<C>
    >;

    private: t_Vectors m_vectors;

    public: template<typename x_Item> void
    Add_Item(x_Item && item)
    {
        m_vectors
            // invoke either Get_MutableItem<B> or Get_MutableItem<C>
            .Get_MutableItem<::std::remove_reference_t<::std::remove_cv_t<x_Item>>>()
            // add item into corresponding std::vector
            .emplace_back(::std::string{}, ::std::forward<x_Item>(item));
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.Add_Item(B{});
    C c{};
    a.Add_Item(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use "generic getter" for your vector:

```
class A
{
public:

    template <typename T>
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, T>>& getVector() {
        auto vectors = std::tie(V1, V2);
        return std::get<std::vector<std::pair<std::string, T>>&>(vectors);
    }

    template <class T>
    void addElement(T Obj) {
        getVector<T>().emplace_back(Obj.Name, Obj);
    }

    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, B>> V1;
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, C>> V2;
};
```

Changing your member might make sense to have `std::tuple` directly.
and you might want to templatize the whole class:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
class A_Impl
{
private:
    template <typename T>
    decltype(auto) getVector() const {
        return std::get<std::vector<std::pair<std::string, T>>>(Vs);
    }
    template <typename T>
    decltype(auto) getVector() {
        return std::get<std::vector<std::pair<std::string, T>>>(Vs);
    }
public:

    template <class T>
    void addElement(T Obj) {
        getVector<T>().emplace_back(Obj.Name, Obj);
    }
private:
    std::tuple<std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Ts>>...> Vs;
};

using A = A_Impl<B, C>;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use your vectors in a few places you could specialise a template to get the correct vector once, then your main template code can be generic:

```
class A{
public:

  template < typename T >
  void addElement(T obj)
  {
    getVector<T>().push_back(std::make_pair(obj.Name,obj));
  }

  template < typename T >
  T& getElement(size_t index)
  {
    return getVector<T>().at(index).second;
  }

private:
  vector<std::pair<std::string, B>> V1;
  vector<std::pair<std::string, C>> V2;

  template < typename T >
  vector<std::pair<std::string, T>>& getVector();
};

template <>
vector<std::pair<std::string, B>>& A::getVector<B>() { return V1; }
template <>
vector<std::pair<std::string, C>>& A::getVector<C>() { return V2; }
```

Answer (score -1):

What if you make use of the shared BaseClass like this??
You will have to create a common interface for BaseClass, I am not sure how much B and C will differ in terms of functionality though.

```
class BaseClass{
public:
    std::string Name;
};

class B : public BaseClass{
};
class C : public BaseClass{
};

class A{
public:
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>> > V1;
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>> > V2;

    template <class T>  void addElement(T Obj)
    {

        std::pair<std::string, std::unique_ptr<T>> AddedPair(Obj.Name, std::make_unique<T>(Obj));

        if (typeid(T) == typeid(B)) 
            V1.push_back(AddedPair);

        else if (typeid(T) == typeid(C)) 
            V2.push_back(AddedPair);
    }  
};

int main()
{
  A a;
  B b;
  C c;

  a.addElement<B>(b) ;//-> then element b is added to vector V1
  a.addElement<C>(c) ;//-> then element c is added to vector V2
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the functionality to delete the pointers you have just newed up.  Although using a `std::unique_ptr` would fix that.

Comment: Thank you for the observations :)